# Remove scroll bar on SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, css

[image]We have homepage which is the master page/landing page for our SharePoint 2013 site. I have setup  managed navigation on main page navigation section and got all the subsites as tabs next to home page.

After doing that, horizontal scroll bar appereard on main page and the page doesnt fit in one shape, it shows main page content  and when you scroll towards right you will see all the tabs. I wanted to remove the scroll bar and get the all the tabs in two lines may be instead of one complete line.

If I can use this using designer 2013, please advise.. Please find the attachments for preview
Green layout page(How I want the page to be) the other one how the existing page is now.[image]

Comment: I think it should be possible using CSS, if you know how to use developer Tools then you can find the element which hold the Menu item and provide some static width to fit as you want

Comment: I think this link will help you as you wanted https://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/splitting-the-top-navigation-in-two/

Answer (score 1):

Apply the css as below to make Menu in two or more lines without scroll.Add below CSS in master page to reflect the change in all pages.

```
<style>
.ms-breadcrumb-top{
white-space: normal;
}
</style>
```